# How to change icon to a new icon onpressed in flutter?

Tags: flutter

just a simple scenario of Like Button

```
body: Center(
    child: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up_alt_outlined),
      onPressed: (){
        /*change to this*/ Icon(Icons.thumb_up_alt_rounded); //how??
      },
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a boolean variable to show different icons based on boolean value

```
bool liked = true;
```

```
IconButton(
  icon: Icon(
    liked ? Icons.thumb_up : Icons.thumb_down,
  ),
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      liked = !liked;
    });
  },
),
```

Comment: It is giving me this error > Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.

Comment: Oh sorry you just missed "icon:" (this will take Icon( liked?.....) as widget)...I dont what to call this...maybe a constructer???
Edit: Yup this worked. Please edit your code with correction so other person will not get any errors